# share ethernet connexion to ethernet usb adaptor thanks to raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2, ethernet, vpn, usb-hub

I try to connect my ps4 with my vpn connexion without using the computer. I install the vpn on a raspberry pi 2 and i connect my raspberry to internet by the ethernet connexion. I use the raspberry with SSH on my laptop. I also have an usb/ethernet shield and I want to plug this shield on my raspberry in order to share the ethernet connexion through usb/ethernet adaptor. Do you know how can i configure my usb/ethernet shield as output on my raspberry pi2 ?
Thank you

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Sorry, i edit my message and ask my question

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet shields are neither input or output, they are both. Generally they are used as a transceiver where data is sent and received by the same shield over the same cable. If you can open a web page with it, it is working just fine both sending and receiving. I believe your best solution is to purchase a small ethernet switch, they are only a few shekels and already debugged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that ethernet/usb shield are input or output. But is it not necessary to define the ethernet/usb shield as output on my raspberry like the same thing on windows for exemple ? Because if i use the ethernet port of my pi2 as input and i plug the ethernet shield on the usb, how do the pi2 know that usb port is output for sharing connexion?

Comment: That would be software on the Pi and defined by the protocol you are using.  For it to share it has to receive a request so somebody else knows it exists unless your protocol uses some form of broadcast.